# output array to strings inside function

Tags: php, arrays, string, function

I have a method that is running a PHP String Function based on user input. I am gathering all of the parameters from the user form and applying it into the method which builds the helper and returns the data. However, I need to be able to output each array node/segment as a separate string inside the function build.

So the user data is collected as follows:

2 parameters, 1 function, 1 subject

Parameters: " " and "_"
Function: "str_replace"
Subject: "This Test"

the parameters are collected as an array that end up like this:

`$parameters(" ", "_")`    <-- Array

I was trying it by imploding it like this:

```
$parameters = "'".implode("','",$parameters)."'";
```

and this:

```
$parameters = implode(',',$parameters);
```

This 'appears' to do what I need by giving me:

```
$parameters = " ,_"
```

or

```
$parameters = "' ','_'";
```

But when I try to build the PHP String Function, it would fail due to the parameters being a single string rather than separate strings.

I was attempting to return my data to the user like this:

```
$data = $myFunction($parameters, $subject);
return $data;
```

I can't run a "loop" inside the function call, so I am hitting a brick wall now. How can I count or know how many parameters are passed so that I can pass them like they need to be?

It would need to be (in this case):

```
$data = $myFunction($parameter1, $parameter2, $subject);
```

But this would change depending on the parameters and function provided.

---

*** EDIT ***

So using var_export, I still do not know how to insert the unknown number of elements into the function build...

var_export gives me the multi dimensional array results, but I can get those a number of ways. My issue comes into trying to insert them into the function build here:

```
$data = $myFunction( HERE , $subject);
```

In which ' HERE ' would need to be the dump...

I NEED to be able to do something like:

```
$data = $myFunction(foreach($parameters as $parameter){$parameter.','}, $subject);
```

(If that makes more sense...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It exists a built-in function to do this: [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). This function require as first arguments the desired function name and an array with all arguments as second argument. So you have to append `$subject` to `$parameters` and call it in this way:

```
$function   = "str_replace";
$subject    = "This Test";
$parameters = [ " " , "_" ];

$parameters[] = $subject;
echo call_user_func_array( $function, $parameters );
```

Will output:

```
This_Test
```

I suppose that your code is intended to load more than one function: the main problem with this is that you divide function arguments in two categories (subject and parameters), so what is the criterion to joining it? In the provided case is simple, but if the “subject” is not the last function argument, how can you proceed?

And if there is a function with two or more variable parameters?

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
$function   = "str_replace";
$parameters = [ " " , "_", "" ];  // array with ALL default parameters
$replace    = [ 2 ];              // array with index of customizable parameters
$subject    = [ "This Test" ];    // array with custom parameters

foreach( $subject as $key => $val )
{
    $parameters[ $replace[ $key ] ] = $val;
}
echo call_user_func_array( $function, $parameters );
```

So, having this set of parameters:

```
$function   = "strpos";
$parameters = [ "My Basical Basic Text" , '', 0 ];
$replace    = [ 1, 2 ];

$subject    = [ 'Basic' ];
```

calling your function you will obtain: “3” (string position of “Basical”), while modifying `$subject` in this way:

```
$subject    = [ 'Basic', 4 ]; //11
```

you will obtain “11” (string position of “Basic”).

Please also note that [language constructs](http://php.net/manual/it/reserved.keywords.php) are not callables by `call_user_func_array()`.

---

- Read more about [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)
- Read more about [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Comment: Thanks! This got me to where I needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

you want vars/arrays as strings ?

```
var_export($data, true)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Comment: I understand that, but how can I get that to work in the function call? THAT is where I am hung up. I updated the OP to show a better example of the problem...